# Measure similarity between $2$ variable length sequences using LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

I would like to build a model that measures the similarity between $2$ sequences that have different lengths.

**Input**: $[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{n-1}, a_n]$ and $[b_1, b_2, \dots, b_{m-1}, b_m]$
where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are sets of features.

**Output**: score $s \in \mathbb{R}$

More precisely, I want to measure the similarity between $2$ **signatures**, where a signature is defined as a **sequence of features**, measured while the signature is being handwritten, every $\Delta t$ seconds. The set of features comprises timestamp, azimuth, altitude, pressure, $(x,y)$ coordinates on the tablet ...

My first idea is to feed a LSTM with $n$ data points (data point $=$ features at given time $t$) of each sequence; which is $2n$ data points because we are comparing $2$ sequences of data points.

1. Does this sound like something that could work?
2. I have a dataset collected from $5$ users. For each user, I have 20 genuine signatures and 20 forged signatures. Is this enough?

Comment: You should spell out LSTM, what does it mean?

Comment: Long short-term memory, google it :)